# How to .dot in pyspark (AttributeError: 'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'dot')

Tags: python, pandas, pyspark

In pandas we know `df1.dot(df2.T)` for dot  product but when I run in pySpark

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-7-2219b97587ee> in <module>
----> 1 df1.dot(df2.T)

/opt/cloudera/parcels/CDH-7.1.3-1.cdh7.1.3.p0.4992530/lib/spark/python/pyspark/sql/dataframe.py in __getattr__(self, name)
   1302         if name not in self.columns:
   1303             raise AttributeError(
-> 1304                 "'%s' object has no attribute '%s'" % (self.__class__.__name__, name))
   1305         jc = self._jdf.apply(name)
   1306         return Column(jc)

AttributeError: 'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'dot'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried [`pandas-on-spark`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/user_guide/pandas_on_spark/index.html)?

```py
import pyspark.pandas as ps
ps.set_option('compute.ops_on_diff_frames', True)

df = ps.DataFrame([[0, 1, -2, -1], [1, 1, 1, 1]])
s = ps.Series([1, 1, 2, 1])

print(df @ s)

0   -4
1    5
dtype: int64
```

### Notes

- `pyspark.pandas` requires `pyspark >= 3.2`
- The dot product works only for operations between Dataframe (dot) Series. So you cannot use it for something like: `df @ df`
- To convert from `spark RDD` to `pandas-on-spark` you can use something like: `pdf = df.to_pandas_on_spark()`
- To go back from `pandas-on-spark` to `spark RDD`, use: `pdf.to_spark()`